# How to skip any error in chunk and to continue with next chunk items?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-batch

I created Reader, Processor and Writer.
I defined size of chunk as 5.
I have one operation in Processor for each item.
I have two transactions in Writer. Update DB for all 5 items and confirm transaction for all 5 items on another place.
My items don't depends on each other, so if one of them failed, the other items doesn't care, they want to be proceeded.

Use Case 1:

If it failed in Processor with any kind of exception (RESTful exception, any java exception, DB exception, runtime exception), let say 2nd item, I want to continue with 3rd, 4th and 5th item.
If it failed on 4th item I want to continue with 5th item.
So, with skip, as I understand, when this chunk with failed item in Processor failed I can repeat this chunk but without 2nd and 4th items (which failed), right?
And if Writer goes well, both transactions are commited after chunk and jog start next chunk with next 5 items, right?

Use Case 2:

No matter if chunk is new or repeated Use Case 1 without that 2 items, if in Writer failed second transaction I want to rollback first transaction without manually doing rollback and commit.
So, if Write throws exception it will automatically rollback first transaction.
And that is good.
But what I want is that even there was exception and transaction rolled back (for that chunk), I want to continue with next chunk on same way, with same behaviour, and so on to the last chunk.

To achive Use Case 1 I guess I have to configure step as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class BatchConfiguration {

private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
private final MyItemReader myItemReader;
private final MyItemProcessor myItemProcessor;
private final MyItemWriter myItemWriter;

private final SimpleJobExecutionListener simpleJobExecutionListener;
private final MyChunkListener myChunkListener;

private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
private final DataSource dataSource;





public BatchConfiguration(
        JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        MyItemReader myItemReader,
        MyItemProcessor myItemProcessor,
        MyItemtWriter myItemWriter,
        SimpleJobExecutionListener simpleJobExecutionListener,
        MyChunkListener myChunkTransactionListener,
        DataSource dataSource,
        ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    this.myItemReader = myItemReader;
    this.myItemProcessor = myItemProcessor;
    this.myItemWriter = myItemWriter;
    this.simpleJobExecutionListener = simpleJobExecutionListener;
    this.myChunkListener = myChunkListener;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
public Job registrationChunkJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("MyJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(simpleJobExecutionListener)
            .flow(step()).end().build();
}

@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutorStepPush() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(4);
    taskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix(LoggingUtil.getWeblogicName() + "-");
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Step step() {
    DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
    attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
    attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED.value());

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").<MyObject, MyObject>chunk(5)
            .reader(myItemReader)
            .processor(myItemProcessor)
            .faultTolerant()
            .writer(myItemWriter)
            .listener(myChunkListener)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutorStepPush())
            .throttleLimit(5)
            .transactionAttribute(attribute)
            .build();
}
```

My job is not scheduled. I start next job manually when current job is finished, successful or not.
As I said, I don't change flag in DB from Writer, so if it failed and some data are skipped and not updated in DB (Writer), when job is finished and after 1h it will start new job and try with same (and maybe new) items from DB (Reader will select them because flag will not be updated as processed).

But somehow, this doesn't work and it's late and I can't see why.
It takes 5 items in chunk, and it didn't failed in Processor, but it failed in Writer while tried to commit 2 transactions (second one failed). It repeat chunk but only with one item, with first item and tried it 2 times (with one item, first item) and than marked job as Failed and stop. Which I don't want. There is so much items to be selected from DB which could be good one.

I don't want to repeat same chunk if it failed from Writer. I want to repeat chunk only if it failed in Processor (to get good one only).
Also, if chunk failed, I don't want job to stop, I want job to continue with next chunk and so on...
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to skip any error in chunk and to continue with next items?

To do that, you need to configure which exceptions should cause the item to be skipped, as explained it the [Configuring Skip Logic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip) section.

According to your configuration, you did not specify any skippable exception. Your step definition should be something like:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
   DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
   attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
   attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED.value());

   return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").<MyObject, MyObject>chunk(5)
        .reader(myItemReader)
        .processor(myItemProcessor)
        .faultTolerant()
        // add skip configuration
        .skipLimit(10)
        .skip(MySkippableException.class)
        .writer(myItemWriter)
        .listener(myChunkListener)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutorStepPush())
        .throttleLimit(5)
        .transactionAttribute(attribute)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: 1. if I want to skip as much as possible, what then, to put limit to chunk size? 2. if I want to skip for any error, what then? But all this are for skipping errors inside chunk while processing items, right? This is also what I want, but I want one more thing...I want to go for next chunk, next 5 items even if current chunk ended as FAILED...is this possible? I need it to be FAILED because I have 2 transactions in Writer so I want them to be as one transaction, if second transaction failed to rollback first transaction and I want to be done automatically, not by hand(me to commit or rollback)

Comment: 1. Nothing prevents you from putting a high skip limit. Usually, the number of skipped items is not very high. If you have to skip a very high number of items, then you have something fundamentally wrong with your input data. 2. With skippable exceptions, the chunk will be scanned item by item and then the job will continue with next chunks. You can find an example that explains chunk scanning here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#chunk-scanning-sample. If this is still not enough for you, then you need a custom writer.

Comment: 1. this limit is per chunk or per job? I thought it is per chunk, so if I have 5 items in chunk max skipped items is 5, no? 2. Ok, thnx I will look at it. But, this is not my major issue (skipping items). My major issue is how to configure job that if chunk failed (and I want to be failed on exception, to have transaction rollback functionality automatically out of the box), go normally to next chunk (next 5 items) and not to stop job as failed. Is it possible?

Comment: 1. yes the limit is per job. 2. As said previously, if a chunk fails and chunk scanning is activated (aka a skippable exception is configured), then the chunk is scanned and the job will continue to next chunks. If chunk scanning is not activated (aka no skippable exception is configured), the job will fail at the first failed chunk.

Comment: Thanks. So, is there a way to have transaction rollback functionality out of the box (exception in chunk, let say in Writer) but to declare chunk as not failed so Job can continue with next chunk?

Comment: @mahmoud-been-hassine, is this possible?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine , in my reader i am fetching records from cosmos db. one record is failed due to wrong java Enum value is mapped resulting into IllegalStateException during deserialisation.  remaining two records has correct structure. now when i enabled skip(Exception.class)&skipLimit(10), it is not processing other chunks also and exiting completely without any error. My total item count in DB is 3 and page size is 3000 & chunk size is 1. please suggest.

Comment: I can't suggest without seeing the code with an example. Please ask a separate question with all details and i will try to help.